# How to convert blob: image to base 64 or any other format so image will show on angular 6?

Tags: angular, text-editor

I am using Rich Text Editor &  uploading my image from local but when show his source code image path is start with blob: how can i remove blob: and print normally my image.

Answer (score 0):

```
var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
 reader.onloadend = function() {
     base64data = reader.result;                
     console.log(base64data);
 }
```

Comment: I need to add this on my component.ts file ?

Comment: Inside the function where you need to do that